# Is this claim true for multivariable functions

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Today, I am asking to verify the continuity of the following multivariable function: $$f(x,y,z)=\begin{cases}\frac{xz-y^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}&,\quad(x,y,z)\neq(0,0,0)\\{}\\0&,\quad(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)\end{cases}$$

The continuity can be easily rejected by seeing that the function has no limit at origin when we consider it on two paths: $$(x,0,0), ~~f\to 0 \quad \text{and} \quad (0,y,0), ~~f\to -1$$  As it is clear, this function is *homogenous of degree zero* also, so:

> Can we say all the multivariable functions   having *the property above* has no limit at the origin?

Indeed, we encounter many multivariable functions $\Bbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ or $\Bbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ and are asked to probe the continuity at the origin. I'd like you to light my mind about this point. Thanks for the time.

Comment: Surely not - constant functions are homogeneous of degree zero as well

Comment: @Cocopuffs: So are we supposed to exclude constant function? In fact, I want to find a basic fast criteria for these functions and their limits at the origin.

Comment: Please do not delete questions with good answers. Others have devoted effort to answer your question; deleting the question is disrespectful of their effort and prevents others from benefiting from your question and its answers.

Comment: @robjohn: Dear Rob, honestly, in that time; I didn't get any attentions to this question and thought maybe this one was not proper as it should be. So, I decided to remove it. I do know the points you kindly noted me. Thanks for remarking me that. I'll do that. Never happens again.  ;-)

Comment: If $p(x,y,z)$ and $q(x,y,z)$ are both homogeneous of the same degree, then their quotient $f(x,y,z)=p(x,y,z)/q(x,y,z)$ is constant on any line through the origin, because for all real numbers $t$ we have $f(x_0,y_0,z_0)=f(tx_0,ty_0,tz_0).$ So for $f$ to have a limit at the origin, that constant has to be independent of the direction of the line. In other words, $f$ has to be a constant itself. If the denominator is homogeneous of a higher degree, then something will always break down, when you approach the origin...

Comment: cont'd: If OTOH the numerator is of a higher degree, then the denominator has to be positive definite, for otherwise the denominator will vanish on some lines thru the origin, and unless those are also zeros of the numerator (meaning that you could have cancelled a factor), you will run into problems.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thank for the time you gave. So If it is possible make the comments as an answer below. Thanks again, I found the point.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$f(x,y,z):=\frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,\,,\;\;g(x,y,z):=x^2+y^2+z^2\,\,,\,\,etc.$$

are homogeneous functions (I'm not sure what you mean by "order" here), yet their limit when $\,(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0)\,$ exists, so I suppose one has to check each case separatedly.

Comment: I meant $f(tx,ty,tz)=t^0f(x,y,z)$.

Comment: The limit of $f$ doesn't exist. Consider $f(x,0,0)$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: You're right, Javier. Thanks. Edited